# Linq not populating the other list

Tags: c#, linq

For some reason the 2nd list `List2` isn't being populated, when it should.

```
        var List1 = new List<object1>();
        //populated List1 here

        var List2 = new List<object1>();

        List1.OrderByDescending(o => o.Cnt).Take(10).Select(s =>
        {
            List2.Add(s);
            return s;
        });
```

`List2` should have 10 entries by now, but doesn't? How is it possible?

Comment: I dont know why, but that is not the way you normally do it. the correct way is List2 = List1.OrderByDescending(o => o.Cnt).Take(10).ToList();

Comment: I need to append to list2, not overwrite it, since it's populated too

Comment: Your _LINQ query_ will not be executed until you start iterating through the projected sequence or call `ToList()`, this behavior is called deferred execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because LINQ expressions are lazily evaluated. That `Select` function is not actually executed until you iterate over it, which you never do.

If you add a `.ToList();` to the end, you should see it working.

**However**, that is not the idiomatic way to do what you're trying to do. As a commenter suggested, something like this would be much better:

```
var List2 = List1.OrderByDescending(o => o.Cnt).Take(10).ToList();
```

Or to add the values to an already populated list,

```
List2.AddRange(List1.OrderByDescending(o => o.Cnt).Take(10));
```

Comment: What if i need to append to list2?  This overwrites list2

Answer (score 2):

It's because Linq static functions are using Lazy execution that means they only executes the code when they need to.

That means only when you use methods like `Count()`, `ToList()` etc' .NET will give you the result you desire and start execute the code you wanted.

You can achieve the result you want through appending `.ToList()` to the end of your `.Select()`.

But a better solution will be using other means.

Answer (score 2):

It's a lazy evaluation problem.  You are not doing anything with the Select, so the adds are not happening.    If you do this, it will work:

```
var resultList = List1.OrderByDescending(o => o.Cnt).Take(10).Select(s =>
{
    List2.Add(s);
    return s;
}).ToList();  //Now List2 has 10 items.
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens, because enumerables are lazily evaluated. The code in the `Select` will only be executed when you start iterating over the enumerable (i.e. consume it).

This allows you for instance to create enumerables that (potentially) return an infinite number of results, like in:

```
public static class MyInfiniteEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> GetIt()
    {
        var x = 0;
        while (true)
            yield return x + 1;
    }
}
```

In your code, to start filling the `List2` you will need to "consume" the `IEnumerable` by iterating over its elements until it is done. For instance like this:

```
var myEnum = List1.OrderByDescending(o => o.Cnt).Take(10).Select(s =>
{
    List2.Add(s);
    return s;
});
foreach (var e in myEnum)
    ; // do nothing, just iterate.
```

More useful would be:

```
var list2 = List1.OrderByDescending(o => o.Cnt).Take(10).ToList();
```

Or

```
list2.AddRange(List1.OrderByDescending(o => o.Cnt).Take(10));
```